# Broken formatting while displaying both start and end date

Tags: 7, datetime

I added Event content type in D7 and I have there Event **Start date**. I setup this field to collect an **End day** + it is collecting time and have option to check "All Day Event".

What I have in the exit when I created new Event is something like:

> ```
> Frida2013, 20-Sunda2013, 22, Frida2013, 20-Sunda2013, 22eptember Frida2013, 20-Sunda2013, 22, 2013 - h:ia(All day)-(All day)
> ```

When I go to Manage Display tab, I can set there for Event Date to display only Start Day for example and then this broken formatting disappears. But I need to be able to display both Start and End date.

Any suggestions appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Juts found a solution. Please create custom formatting like this:

```
D, F d, Y (h:ia)
```

Key here is to wrap time in parentheses

> (h:ia)

after that trick formatting is fixed and looks something like:

> Sat, September 21, 2013 (All day) to Mon, September 30, 2013 (All day)